# Convert html to pdf, adjust the width

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a table with around 10 columns in my html page , when i am converting to pdf, last colums are truncated. how to solve this problem.is there any PDF landscape option?

workin in codeigniter: using dompdf converter

```
 $this->load->plugin('to_pdf');
$this->load->helper('file');
$html     = $this->load->view('export_pdf'), $data, TRUE);
            pdf_create($html, $this->session->userdata('site_id'),TRUE); 
                }
```

I  also used `pdf_create($html, $this->session->userdata('site_id'),TRUE,$papersize = 'a3', $orientation = 'landscape');` but what where paper size and orientation i give the result issame

Comment: Converting how? Using what tool?

Comment: ah, okay. It might be helpful if you added a link to the exact version

Comment: what is the paper size you are using.?

Comment: pdf_create($html, $this->session->userdata('site_id'),TRUE,$papersize = 'a3', $orientation = 'landscape');   i gave as above but what where paper size and orientation i give the result issame

Comment: Some questions: Have you checked the HTML prior to passing it to DOMPDF? Do you have a sample document? Have you specified widths for each column? DOMPDF will try to fit the table, but sometimes is unable to do so. Finally, if you're using the plugin with DOMPDF 0.5.1 you might try updating to the 0.6.0 beta 2 to see if it works any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
pdf_create($html, $this->session->userdata('site_id'),TRUE, 'a3', 'landscape');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using codeigniter, with dompdf helper you can use this modification in helpers/dompdf_helper.php

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function pdf_create($html, $filename, $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_paper("a4");
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename . ".pdf");
}

function pdf_create_params($html, $filename, $stream=TRUE, $paper = 'a4', $orientation = "portrait") 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_paper($paper, $orientation);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename . ".pdf");
}

?>
```

Instead calling pdf_create call pdf_create_params and use the params you want. By default it has A4 and portrait.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I did not manage to adjust my columns width after using :

```
$htmlToPdf->WriteHTML($this->view->render($fileRender));
```

To solve this, just apply the style attribute to your **td** too, in your view file

```
<td style:"width:10%;"> </td>
```